# Wire to Receptacle Only Shows 1.9V

Tags: wiring, voltage

Went to use the garbage disposal yesterday and it didn't work.  At first I thought it might have tripped its internal fuse, but no dice—I pushed the button on the bottom with no effect.  Then I thought the (GFCI) receptacle might have burned out, so I put in a spare—also no effect.  I pulled voltage from the hot screw to ground and neutral and it was only pulling 1.1V.  I also disconnected the receptacle from the wires, and got 1.9V.  Replacing the circuit breaker had no effect.

Ideas?  TIA!

Edit: discovered that I am partly an idiot—I was measuring the voltage with the wall switch off :-o  However, with the switch on, I do only get about 50V, still less than the 120 I should be.

Comment: Voltage at the breaker? Voltage at the switch? It's bad connection (usual) or bad wire (less usual) somewhere - somewhere being between where it's good, and where it's bad.

Comment: Now we do not trust your measurements (following your Edit).  Do you have 120 V on the switch incoming hot? Do you have 120 V on the GFCI ? where is the GFCI located  ? How about circuit breaker in the main panel ? If you have 120 V outgoing on the main panel, then it is the wire somewhere. Do you have a junction box. What else is on the circuit and not working ?

Comment: I will check the switch.

Comment: Looks like it was the switch.  Whoever installed it used the backstabs, which must have gone bad.

Answer (score 2):

Would imagine something wrong with the cable/wires.

Maybe at a junction box or you have mice(fried) in the walls.

If you replaced the outlet and the circuit breaker, only the cable/wire are left to check.

1.1 or 1.9 volts can be phantom voltage the wires are picking up from another close cable somewhere.

You checked the two ends that are easy, now you need to check the centre that can be hard. Start with the switch, then go on to any other boxes on the circuit.

Comment: The OP said there was a switch involved, but no mention of replacing it.  Maybe it is one of those notorious back-stab switches and the connection failed.   To diagnoise further, with the power off, pull it out, inspect for obvious damage, then turn the power back on and measure power to ground.  The switch may also have failed internally.

Comment: Looks like it was the switch. Whoever installed it used the backstabs, which must have gone bad.